# WPF Textbox TAB spaces

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anybody know how can I control the number of spaces for the TAB character that is displayed in a WPF textbox?
I can see that the default is 8, but didn't find any property to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible. Sad true.

[Here is an old link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/00c1ea7f-0a2c-4290-bdc3-26685c77f5aa), but it doesn't seem to change much since then.